# VM Connected to a Domain

Tags: windows, virtualization, domain, command-line-interface, vmware-vcenter

I'm working with an automated tool that deploys VMs to center. It is setup within the customspec to be connected to a domain [windows]. After the VM is clone, we get a success state from VMWare that the VM is ready, however... it tends to be the case that the VM isn't finished being configured. [And thusly not on the domain]

Is there anyway, CLI based, to confirm that the VM being deployed is connected to a domain?

Comment: What is the automated tool?

Comment: Its HP Operations Orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

Orchestrator has an [Active Directory plugin](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VCO_AD_PLUGIN_103&productId=285), I don't know it or use it but there's a chance you might be able to do a check via that as part of a deployment workflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
dsquery computer -name $HOSTNAME
```

will let you know if the computer account exists in the domain for $HOSTNAME.

Comment: Where would that be run on? I have access to the machine it's self... but I don't have the information if it is on a specific domain or not

Comment: This can be run on any machine that is a member of the domain in question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by sending the following command to the box [via a privileged account]

```
wmic computersystem list brief /format:list
```